# Como abrir uma outra Activity a partir de um Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Preciso chamar uma `Activity` a partir de um item de um `navigation drawer`. Alguém pode ajudar?

Esses são os itens que quero chamar para as `Activity`s:

```
     public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {



    } else if (id == R.id.nav_programacao) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_galeria) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_visitar_site) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_instagran) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_facebook) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_twitter) {



    }
```

Comment: Você sabe abrir outras `Activity`s e está tendo problema só com esse caso ou você não sabe abrir `Activity`s?

Comment: não sei abrir ainda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo que a `Activity` que você quer abrir se chama `MinhaAtividade`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MinhaAtividade.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

`this` aqui é o contexto do `Intent`. Estou pressupondo que você está dentro de uma `Activity` ou outra subclasse de `Context`. Se não estiver, adapte esse parâmetro. A mesma coisa vale para o `startActivity`.

Comment: Pablo, o meu problema é como eu chamo a Activity quando clicar em algum desses itens, qual o evento que utilizo.

Comment: A julgar pelos seus ifs e pela sua resposta, pareceu que você já tinha passado dessa parte. Coloque mais do seu código, então, e explique melhor qual é o problema.

Comment: Suponha que escolho o item nav_programação, quando clicasse queria que ele chamasse para activity programação, é esse o contexto do meu problema, entedeu?

Comment: Seria interessante ver pelo menos o código que rodeia esses seus ifs, para evitar de escrever outra resposta que não é o que você deseja.

Comment: para visualizar melhor coloquei na pergunta principal...

Comment: Então, você já tem o método que responde ao clique. Basta colocar o código similar ao que eu escrevi, substituindo a `MinhaAtividade` pela `Activity` que você quer abrir em cada um dos casos.

Comment: entendido..resolvi

Answer (score 3):

### Para chamar uma nova Activity(Atividade):

Crie uma nova `Activity` com o nome de `MainActivity2` e insira este código abaixo em seu método `onNavigationItemSelected` de sua `MainActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class); 
startActivity(intent);
```

---

### Para chamar um novo Fragment(Fragmento):

Crie um novo `Fragment` com o nome de `novoFragment` e insira este código abaixo em seu método `onNavigationItemSelected` de sua `MainActivity`:

```
novoFragment fragment = new novoFragment();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTrasaction =
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTrasaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTrasaction.commit();
```

### ** Aviso Importante **

Para que a chamada deste `fragment` se conclua com sucesso (funcione), é necessário seguir este post mais completo sobre o assunto: [Menu de 3 pontos em todas as Activities com o padrão Navigation Drawer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119551/navigation-drawer-em-todas-as-telas/119561)

---

### Em sua MainActivity - Solução na prática:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // abrindo um novo fragment
     novoFragment fragment = new novoFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTrasaction =
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTrasaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTrasaction.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery)  {
    // abrindo um nova activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class); 
    startActivity(intent);    
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tenta assim Marcos, no exemplo abaixo vc tenta verificar se existe o app, passando o nome do pacote:

```
this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?user_id=USERID"));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

ou neste outro exemplo vc deixa o usuário escolher qual app quer utlizar, vc apenas envia uma texto.

```
Intent it = new Intent();
it.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
it.putExtra(it, "SUA MENSAGEM");
it.setType("text/plain");
```

Answer (score 0):

Crie um método e chame as Activitys que vc deseja:

```
private void callActivity(Class c){
    Intent it = new Intent(this, c);
    startActivity(it);
}
```

Comment: Note que esse método só funciona se estiver dentro de um `Context`

Comment: Arthur, dá uma olhada no codigo na pergunta principal

Comment: Desculpa Marcos, deixa eu ver se entendi agora, vc gostaria de chamar por exemplo nav_twitter uma intent que abra diretamente o Twitter app? É isso?

Comment: sim, Arthur....