# Como modificar o Navigation Drawer para chamar uma Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment, android-activity

Gente eu criei um navigation drawer pela galeria do google (Navigation Drawee Activity) e gostaria de modificar ela para quando eu clicar no menu em vez de chamar um arquivo extent Fragment chamar uma Activity normal, (extent Activity), eu vejo tentando do jeito tradicional usando Intent porem nunca da certo, o aplicativo sempre fecha, me ajudem

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.botao_tela_status) {

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.conteudo_fragmento, new FragmentoStatusTela()).commit();

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        if (id == R.id.nav_quiz_tela) {

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.conteudo_fragmento, new FragmentoQuiz()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.desafio2) {


        } else if (id == R.id.desafio3) {

        } else if (id == R.id.desafio4) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}


public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }
}
```

```css
12-18 17:32:17.776 3532-3532/com.example.alexandre.nossa_historia W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
12-18 17:32:17.790 3532-3532/com.example.alexandre.nossa_historia D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-18 17:32:17.791 3532-3532/com.example.alexandre.nossa_historia E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.alexandre.nossa_historia, PID: 3532
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alexandre.nossa_historia/com.example.alexandre.nossa_historia.Main2Activity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:471)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:325)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:286)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
 at com.example.alexandre.nossa_historia.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:11)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
12-18 17:32:20.471 3532-3532/com.example.alexandre.nossa_historia I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3532 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Inclua seu código na pergunta para as pessoas saberem como está sendo feito.

Comment: Assim ajudou ??

Comment: Qual exception da quando tenta abrir uma activity?

Comment: Possível duplicata: [Como abrir uma outra Activity a partir de um Navigation Drawer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118566/2541)

Comment: o erro continua Ramaral, não consigo

Comment: Eu editei o meu código vejam ai por favor

Comment: Poste a exception junto para que possamos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Ai está coloquei o erro que da ao clicar

Comment: Recomendo você usar está lib https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer, sempre uso ela para criar um navigation drawer, tem suporte ao android 14 e account header, este vídeo explica como usa-lo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xpA1bY_TX4&t=14s, ela poupa muito código e tempo, bem mais fácil e rápido do que criar do zero